# invoking cmd's command on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

I want to use cmd's command in Visual Studio like "cd:" and etc. 
But, I don't know how to start. Is there Anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: Already searched on the internet? Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx)what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try Open Command Line, can be found here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e84e2cf-2d6b-472a-b1e2-b84932511379

Hope thats what you are looking for.